# Can Windows OS's be forced to notify the user that update downloads are in the process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-update

When update downloads are in process, system resources are obviously being used.  It would be nice to know the Windows Updates downloads have started.  On Windows 7 sometimes the users see a Windows Update icon and the rollover message lets them know downloads are in progress; oddly that doesn't always happen.  On Windows 8 no icons seem readily available; on any of the recent Windows OS's is there a place to force update download notification?.

Is this just thought to be something everyone wants in the background and not to be informed about?  A lot of users want to be notified on the desktop/taskbar to know when such a background process is engaged.

Comment: Windows 8 users the same icon as Windows 7. Do you have your system tray hiding certain system icons? The Windows update icon can be "turned off".

Comment: When I look in Notification Area Icons I don't see an entry for Windows Update, nor when I check the Windows Update applet.  So I guess no, I don't have it turned off, but only because it's not visible to turn off.  Odd?